# How do I use the Python Unsplash API to get a URL of a random image instead of a random photo ID?

Tags: python

I'm using python and the python unsplash api from a github (link below). I am trying to find a way to get the URL of a random photo through the api but instead am met by photo ID. I can't figure out how to find the corresponding URL to go with the photo ID that is returned when using the commands (as shown in my code below).

There are no error messages that come up.

[Python-Unsplash GitHub API Documentation](https://github.com/yakupadakli/python-unsplash/blob/master/README.md)

[Normal Unsplash API Documentation](https://unsplash.com/documentation)

```
from unsplash.api import Api
from unsplash.auth import Auth

client_id = "#this would normally be my access key"         #authenticating
client_secret = ""                                          #my profile
redirect_uri = ""                                           
code = ""

auth = Auth(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, code=code)
api = Api(auth)

img= api.photo.random(orientation = 'landscape' )   #gets id of random photo

print(img)


print(api.photo.get('wzfOt1uwzxc')) #I was hoping this would return URL but doesn't
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python API referenced seems unofficial. Per their documentation, it's impossible to retrieve the URL with an ID.

Try using the Unsplash REST API instead. Per their [documentation](https://unsplash.com/documentation#get-a-random-photo), you should be able to view URLs in the response.

Comment: Thank you for your response. From what I've been able to figure out, I cannot use the official documentation and commands since it is not applicable to python... and so I am unable to use that API instead.

Comment: An API just wraps http requests and handles parsing of the return object. You can make these requests yourself by examining the endpoints on the developer documentation.